# SMD SOT-25 identify component

Tags: pcb, components, repair, damage

Can I ask for help in identifying the following SMD component? Package is SOT-25. Marking is **bPCGD** .
Probably is voltage detector but I dont know his parameters. It is a component of mainboard IP camera YI YHS3017.
I add photos of the mainboard and a diagram of this component that I was able to measure. Pinuot 3 is connected to a nearby coil, pinout 2 is ground, pinout 5 is voltage from power supply (5V).
I`ve looked in many catalogs but it is probably a unique label of the manufacturer. I suspected it might be the BD5242G but it doesn't match the ground pinouts.

Thanks for your help

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. RT9193 has VIN ( Voltage input)to pinouts 1 - in my component VIN (+5V) is connect to pinout 4 ( in the drawn by me pinout 5). Probably VOUT in my component is pinout 1.Ground both is in pinout 2. I wonder what is mean small letter "b" on the marking? Its mean country of production? Or manufacturer designation?

Answer (score 1):

I have looked around, and found also your forum post on a elektroda.pl. But looking further on [this website with code bP](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/bp) and looking through the few ones with package SOT25/SOT3353 I think the correct component is RT9193. Especially because there is a coil connected to pin 4 or pin 5, my first guess was that it is some kind of voltage regulator.
[Datasheet](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT9193/DS9193-16.pdf)